# Displaying styles in Django 1.3 media_url vs. static_url

Tags: python, css, django, web-deployment

I have everything on my live website (Django 1.3) set up save for the styling. Here is what the non-boilerplate code of settings.py looks like:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = "/home2/django/build/projects/static/media/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_ROOT = "home2/django/build/projects/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)
```

Here is what urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings


from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'seeking_alpha.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^about/', 'seeking_alpha.views.about', name = 'about'),
    url(r'^guidelines/', 'seeking_alpha.views.guidelines', name = 'guidelines'),
    url(r'^participation/', 'seeking_alpha.views.participation', name = 'participation'),
    url(r'^evaluation/', 'seeking_alpha.views.evaluation', name = 'evaluation'),
    url(r'^home/', 'seeking_alpha.views.home', name = 'home')
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

and the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    c = {}
    return render(request, "home.html", c)

def about(request):
    c = {}
    return render(request, "about.html", c)

def guidelines(request):
    c = {}
    return render(request, "guidelines.html", c)

def participation(request):
    c = {}
    return render(request, "participation.html", c)

def evaluation(request):
    c = {}
    return render(request, "evaluation.html", c)
```

and finally some code from a template:

```
{% load static %}
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>2015 UChicago Seeking Alpha Pitch Competition</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "style/css" href = "{% get_static_prefix %} participation.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "header">
        <img id = "alpha" src = "{% get_static_prefix %} alpha.jpg" height = "60", width = "250">
```

Written in Django, hosted by Hostgator. All of ht logic works fine (links, content), just none of the css pages or images are going through to what the user sees

Comment: Please provide what {% get_static_prefix %} generate exactly. You can check it in a source code of generated html in you browser.

Comment: example copied directly from source: <div class = "header">
  <img id = "alpha" src = "/static/alpha.jpg" height = "60", width = "250">
  <img id = "uchicago" src =  "/static/uchicago.jpg" height = "80", width = "260">

Comment: I have a directory in the project called source which contains the various media, but it seems as if it's not finding the images in "/static/alpha.jpg" etc

Comment: There's really no reason to be using Django 1.3. That's five versions old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert `/` at the beginning of `STATIC_ROOT` path in you `settings.py`. It should help, because now it is a relative path and you need an absolute one. It should look like this:

`STATIC_ROOT = "/home2/django/build/projects/static/"`

Comment: Doesn't seem like that's changing anything output to the screen - if it makes a difference, I uploaded everything (including the css files) to a media folder and copied the contents into different directories throughout the project to see if it recognized anything. Are the style elements not recognized because they're uploaded media?

Comment: So are your styles not recognized or your media files not recognized or both? Your styles and static files should be in `/home2/django/build/projects/static/` not in `/home2/django/build/projects/static/media/` which should be a directory for only uploaded content

Comment: neither styles nor media files are being recognized. Since I uploaded the css files do those count as uploaded media?

Comment: No. Uploaded means uploaded in example in forms. Media are not part of a source code of a django application, but static files are.

Comment: alright, I moved some things around so that the media folder is within /home2/django/build/projects/static/media/ and the css files are in /home2/django/build/projects/static/. Is this closer? Do you think the error could have something to do with how I defined STATICFILE_DIRS or something else in settings.py?